# How can i make a collision detection like the chain reaction android game in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 2d-games

I'm working on a project that is similar to the android game chain reaction.

The grid and structure is complete. the only problem is getting the collision algo right.

I need a more dynamic solution to this.

Comment: I don't know if it wouldn't be an overkill for your case, but have you considered Box2D : http://www.box2dflash.org/

Comment: Considering this. but i'm confused with how to go ahead with this, especially with the multiple collisions.

Comment: Have you tried `hitTestPoint`?

Comment: Im using hitTestObject. but it's getting to complicated.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you don't have to use complex method like hitTestPoint HitTestObject.

All you have to check is circle radius and distance between circles : (Guess you store the list of your circles somewhere! )

```
for each(var circle1:* in listOfCircle)
{
   for each(var circle2:* in listOfCircle
   {
       if(distance between circle 1 and circle 2 < (circle1 radius/2) + (circle2 radius/2))
       {
          //Collision
       }
   }

}
```

Of course you have to avoid checking distance between same circles.
You can find the distance between 2 points here :
[Distance between two points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722797/distance-between-two-points)

Now if you'r looking for high performance game, I would use Starling Framework immediatly :
http://gamua.com/starling/

But if it's just a personnal project for training everything is alright :)

Comment: I'm taking  your advice and switching to starling. Will give your solution a test and let you know if it works. Thank you!

Comment: @DaltonPereira You might take a look at Adobe Gaming SDK then ! http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/gamingsdk/ , good choice :)